# How to append to an array key's value php

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have an array like this:

`[["code1": '528'], ["code2": '292'], ["code1": '108']]`

I am looping through the array to check if a specific key exists. If it doesn't then I am adding it to another array:

`$arr[$codename] = $code`

However, if the key already exists, then I want to append the `$code` value to the existing key's values. I'm not sure how to do this part.

I want the new array to look like this:

`[["code1": '528', '108'], ["code2", '292']]`

Comment: `["code1": '528', '108']` isn't a valid structure (or at least not in the way you're intending it). A key can't contain multiple values directly. However it can contain another structure which itself can hold multiple values. Perhaps you meant something like `["code1": ['528', '108']]`? i.e. you'd need an array to hold the multiple values belonging to that key.

Comment: @ADyson you're right sorry that's what I meant

Comment: And you might better to create that structure up-front, consistently across all your keys no matter how many items they contain, then the method to access them will be the same in all cases, e.g. `[["code1": ['528', '108']], ["code2", ['292']]]`

Comment: @ADyson Would this be a better way to do it then: `$arr[$codename][] = $code;`

Comment: `I am looping through the array to check if a specific key exists`, keep in mind you don't need to loop the whole array yourself, you could use the built-in function [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: `$arr[$codename][] = $code;`...yeah that would make sense. Give it a try.

Comment: @DarkBee Ahh okk thanks I'll use that

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```php
$array = [['code1' => 528], ['code2' => 292], ['code1' => 108]];

$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $newArray[array_key_first($value)][] = $value[array_key_first($value)];
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [code1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 528
            [1] => 108
        )

    [code2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 292
        )

)
```